When it is raining why the rain drops making a bubbles when they touches the water surface?
I've observed that when raindrops fall on the surface of water, they create a semi-spherical shape. Why does this happen, and what is this phenomenon called ?


This is owing to surface tension and cohesion of water.  It’s called capillary wave, or surface wave formation.
A raindrop hits the water and creates capillary waves (ripples) spreading from the point of impact. The initial impact causes the water to bulge upward into a semi-spherical shape.
The semi-sphere is formed from the water's tendency to minimize potential energy by reducing the surface area to volume ratio. The semi-sphere is one of the shapes that best minimizes surface area while maintaining a given volume.

The formation of bubbles on the surface of water during the rain can happen for two reasons.

Surface tension. Imagine dropping a rock into water. The rock creates a cavity in the water. Air quickly fills the cavity, and when the water envelopes this cavity, an air bubble is formed. The same thing happens with rain drops. The raindrop has a lot of surface tension, and so does the water it falls into. A cavity is created due to the momentum of the rain drop pushing water away in front of it. This cavity is filled with air, and the water fills in behind it, making a bubble.
Raindrops trap gas as they fall through the atmosphere. We often imagine rain drops falling in a teardrop shape, but really they are more spherical or a concave spheroid when large enough. Raindrops are constantly going through cycles of collecting into larger drops, then being torn apart by air resistance. In this process, it's very possible that air gets trapped.


A large portion of this is likely AI-generated.
